# Flutter: json_serializable type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' error

Tags: flutter

I am linking cloud function to my Flutter model. Result is coming from `Cloud-Function`

```
  print(result.data);
  print(result.data.runtimeType);
  GameModel _incomingGame = GameModel.fromJson(result.data);
```

print(result.data);

```
{
    game: 'GTA',
    played: ['ISODATE', ...]
}
```

print(result.data.runtimeType);

```
flutter: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```

GameModel

```
@JsonSerializable()
class GameModel {
  String? game;
  List? played;

  GameModel(
      this.game,
      this.played,);

  factory GameModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GameModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$GameModelToJson(this);
}
```

game_model.g.dart

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'game_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

GameModel _$GameModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GameModel(
      json['game'] as String?,
      json['played'] as List?,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$GameModelToJson(GameModel instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'game': instance.game,
      'played': instance.played,
    };
```

The incoming data result's runtimeType shows that it is `Map<String, dynamic>` in the console. However, when I execute `GameModel.fromJson()`, it causes `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`.

I really don't get that why this is happening somehow? Even if I do something like below also causes the same type cast error.

```
GameModel _gameData = result.data;
var game = GameModel.fromJson(_gameData);
```

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: do you mind share `GameModel` class file too?

Comment: you can try with `jsonDecode`, like  `GameModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(result.data));`

Comment: `jsonDecode(result.data)` returns `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these solutions

```dart
  GameModel _incomingGame = GameModel.fromJson(result.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Or

```dart
  GameModel _incomingGame = GameModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(result.data));
```

It also would be better if you check the types before executing type casts

---

If above solutions doesn't work, add the type when calling cloud functions

```dart
final func = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('gameFunction');
final result = await func<Map<String, dynamic>?>();
```

Comment: Having same problem :/ `Map<String, dynamic> game = Map<String, dynamic>.from(result.data);` and `print(game.runtimeType);` return `Map<String, dynamic>` but as soon as it goes into `.fromJson()`, it turns to `Map<Object?, Object?>`

Comment: Could you write the fromJson method manually? or add the generated method to question @chichi

Comment: I just added the generated model. mongodb -> cloud function -> flutter as `.data()`. Therefore, I have no idea why it is referring as `Map<Object?, Object?>`. And, it totally works normal unless I put them into `fromJson()` :/

Comment: Yeah that's odd, I updated the answer if you are using firebase cloud functions maybe this one works out, @chichi

Comment: Same stuffs. I am just restructuring `result.data` and just use `GameModel();` to add directly to my variable. If I figure it out then I will keep ya update what was the problem bro. Thanks so much for help

Comment: There was one more `object - map` added by mongoose that coming with `data` as `Map<Object?, Object?>`... So, I've added an object to my MongoDB and all these objects are type casted as `Map<Object?, Object?>`.

Comment: My solution is just doing json.encoding the incoming data from firebase and then decode that encoded json to feed the `fromJson()`. To sum up, I am using TS Firebase Function Call (not http) with mongoose. Nested objects and array are causing some trouble `Map<Object?, Object?>` (maybe there is a solution that I apply inside the backend).

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
GameModel.fromJson((result.data as Map<dynamic, dynamic>).cast<String, dynamic>())
```